# Ajax button in list to delete row entry - submit function is called instead of callback

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a themed table on a form. To delete entries in this table I render buttons for each row having a special idx and an ajax callback for each button.

The buttons are rendered perfectly, but when I click on the button, the standard submit routine is called instead of the assigned callback routine. Is there anything I missed?

```
// build header for table
$pheader = array('Name','Action');
// build data array for table
$aPersonsTable = array();
foreach ($aPersons as $key => $value) {
  $form_button['button'.$key] = array(
    '#id' => 'del-p-'.$key,
    '#name' => 'del-p-'.$key,
    '#idx' => $key,
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Delete',
    '#submit' => 'delete_auction_person_ajax_callback_submit',
    '#attributes' => array('class'=>array('ajax-processed')),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'delete_auction_person_ajax_callback',
      'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),
      'effect' => 'fade',
    )
  );
  $deleteButton = drupal_render($form_button['button'.$key]);
  $row = array($value['dname'],$deleteButton);
  $aPersonsTable[]=$row;
}

$form['persons']['ptable'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $pheader,
  '#rows' => isset($aPersonsTable)?$aPersonsTable:null,
  '#disabled' => TRUE,
  '#title' => 'Users currently assigned',
  '#empty' => t('No users assigned yet!'),
  '#prefix' => '<div id="ptable_wrapper">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

Comment: I don't see any use of [`#ajax['prevent']`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax_prevent) in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `'#submit' => 'delete_auction_person_ajax_callback_submit'`, it does not seem necessary. Adding `ajax-processed` class on the button doesn't seem necessary either. The function `delete_auction_person_ajax_callback` receives $form and $form_state, and will tell you what input was clicked that triggered the callback, from there you can do whatever it is you need to do.

I built a lot of tables this way, but I don't think I had the form items as a submit type. If I recall, I used buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You set `#executes_submit_callback` to `false` on your submit button to prevent that the submit callback is executed.

```
$form_button['button'.$key] = array(
    '#id' => 'del-p-'.$key,
    '#name' => 'del-p-'.$key,
    '#idx' => $key,
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Delete',
    '#submit' => 'delete_auction_person_ajax_callback_submit',
    '#executes_submit_callback' => false,
    '#attributes' => array('class'=>array('ajax-processed')),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'delete_auction_person_ajax_callback',
      'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),
      'effect' => 'fade',
    )
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't work better with that line. Clicking the button still submit's the whole document instead of doing an AJAX request.

Comment: Are your rows with the `delete` button generated after an ajax callback ?

Comment: No. They are generated when loading the 'initial' page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent submit, use [#ajax['prevent']](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax_prevent) attribute:

```
'#ajax' => array(
  'callback' => 'delete_auction_person_ajax_callback',
  'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),
  'effect' => 'fade',
  'prevent' => 'submit',
)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I added the prevent line to my code but it has no effect. When I compare my rendered buttons to a working AJAX button there is a class missing in the html code of the rendered button:

`<input type="submit" id="del-p-8c19f571e251e61cb8dd3612f26d5ecf" name="del-p-8c19f571e251e61cb8dd3612f26d5ecf" value="Delete" class="form-submit">
`
There correct AJAX button looks like follows:

`<input type="submit" id="edit-add-person-btn" name="add-person-btn" value="Add person" class="form-submit ajax-processed">`

That may be the problem. But how to solve it? Manually adding the class...

Comment: ... 'ajax-processed' doesn't work.

Comment: Does not work or change anything. Button still not loading via ajax.

Comment: @kwoxer sorry to hear that, but I only pointed to a specific form api prameter. If it got faulty in the meantime, I can't do a thing about it. If your implementation is faulty, I can't know.

Comment: Yeah no problem, but someone else might try this here and it does not work. So I safe his time on trying it out :)